# i need help on if else statement on php code using wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, html, header

Basically I have this code. It shows on header_new when the postId of the wordpress page is part of the array.

Now I want a 3rd option, a new header with id . So it shows up when the its part of a new set of array. I tried else if it didn't work tho.

Can you guys help me add a new php line to do just that. Basically a 3rd else if statement to execute a new header given if it is part of an array.

Please be detailed since I'm a noob at PHP

```
<div id="wrapper" class="<?php echo $post->ID;?>">
<?php $pagesArray = array(7686,7913,7915,8019,8131,8180,8676,8769,8796,8810,8812,8814,8818,8815); ?>`
<?php if(in_array($post->ID, $pagesArray)){ ?>
<div id="header_new"><!--header!-->
    </div><!--header!-->
<?php } else {?>
<div id="header-out">
   </div>
```

Comment: I'm not quite understanding this part of your question.  "Now I want a 3rd option, a new header with id . So it shows up when the its part of a new set of array. I tried else if it didn't work tho."  can you edit an elaborate?

Comment: Can you help me another if else statement on this code. Using PHP

Comment: Is it 
<? php else if{?> Help me please

Comment: @toninoj has your answer below

Answer (score 1):

You cannot order your code like this:

```
if (something){
    xxxxx
} else {
    xyxyx
} else if (something else) {
    zzzzz
}
```

because your loop ends with else. `else if` must come before `else` case, because `else`
finishes the loop. The third `else if` will never be fulfilled.

Edit:

When you put your second else if, you need to specify your test.
it is `else if(test clause){some execution}`.

Here is a link, this may help you out: [Php else if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Comment: so can it be like this?

<div id="wrapper" class="<?php echo $post->ID;?>">
<?php $pagesArray = array(7686,7913,7915,8019,8131,8180,8676,8769,8796,8810,8812,8814,8818,8815); ?>`
<?php if(in_array($post->ID, $pagesArray)){ ?>
<div id="header_new"><!--header!-->
    </div><!--header!-->
<?php }else if {?>
<?php } else {?>
<div id="header-out">
   </div>

Comment: I edited my answer. Please accept it if it helped you.
By the way, you don't need to go twice into php mode here :

<?php $pagesArray = array(7686,7913,7915,8019,8131,8180,8676,8769,8796,8810,8812,8814,8818,8815); ?>` <?php if(in_array($post->ID, $pagesArray)){ ?> 

You can do it all in one piece, like this:

<?php $pagesArray = array(7686,7913,7915,8019,8131,8180,8676,8769,8796,8810,8812,8814,8818,8815);  if(in_array($post->ID, $pagesArray)){ ?>